# Prolog - Check if a element not in a specified position in list

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and now I'm get stuck with this clue "element E not in the position 4th in list L"

```
L = [_,_,_,E] => false
```

I've compared list as

```
set_equal([],[]).
set_equal([H|T],R):-
   member(H,R),
   remove(H,R,Rez),
   set_equal(T,Rez).
```

Then I use some stupid ways like that

```
notin4(X,L):-
      set_equal([X,_,_,_],L)
   ;  set_equal([_,X,_,_],L)
   ;  set_equal([_,_,X,_],L).
```

or

```
notin4(X,L):- not(set_equal([_,_,_,X],L).
```

But it doesn't work :(

Can anyone point me out another way to solve this clue? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by "But it doesn't work"? What does it do instead?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Actualy, the problem can be solved without this clue (and result is OK). I added this clue to test whether my prolog code for type "E not in 4th in L" is correct. However, after I add this clue, the output result go wrong.

Comment: proper Prolog way: `notin4(X,[_,_,_,X|_]) :- !, fail.`

Comment: @CapelliC. Can you describe more detail about your approach. I want to understand more clearly :( thank you very much...

Comment: it's the standard Prolog syntax for the snippet you started with: `L = [_,_,_,E] => false`. If the head of the rule gets matched, it means X **is** in 4 position, then cut any further search and fail. You can't get any simpler than that, and will work on **any** Prolog implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *easiest* way would be:

```
list_not_nth(List, N, X) :-
    nth1(N, List, Y),
    dif(X, Y).
```

If you knew you are looking for the 4th element, you could do:

```
list_not_4th([_,_,_,X|_], Y) :-
    dif(X, Y).
```

Comment: @ThaiHQ First you really need to explain what you are doing and what is your problem. Now your question and comments read like little riddles.

Comment: Ohhh. It's OK now. I understand problem :D. thank you for your support.